# How would I write a function that takes in an array of positive integers and returns an array of the factorials on the numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, refactoring

I would like a function that takes in an array of positive integers and returns the factorials of those integers - using the `.map` or `.reduce` methods maybe?

e.g

`[2, 4, 6]` returns `[2, 24, 720]`

The below code works correctly when it is a single integer, but does not return anything when an array is passed.

```js
function factorial(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
  }
}

factorial(5); // 120
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value. [See more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

With `.map()` you can do it like this-

```
function factorialize(num) {
 if (num < 0) 
   return -1;
 else if (num == 0) 
   return 1;
 else {
   return (num * factorialize(num - 1));
 }
}
const numbers = [2,4,6];
const factorial = numbers.map(n => factorialize(n))
console.log(factorial)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call `.map` with your current function:

```js
const factorial = (n) => {
  if (n === 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
  }
}
const factorials = arr => arr.map(factorial);
console.log(factorials([2, 4, 6]));
```